# How to get Spring rest API response in java code?

Tags: java, spring, api

I done Spring rest api .that is returning json data now i want to call that api in my system(remote by ip) .how to get that response in my java code
Or Rest Template.

```
{[
  {
    "deviceId": 1,
    "userId": "100",
    "userName": "Jee",
    "date": "2016-09-19 00:00:00.000"
  },
  .
  .
  .
  n

]}
```

how to read in java using rest Template .

Comment: What does each item in the list represent? A list of what?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is consuming a rest api in Java. [This](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) should get you started.

Comment: i have post api

Answer (score 0):

Its a pretty much a basic need and its all over the web on how to consume rest apis.

[This](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) and [this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-use-spring-resttemplate-0) are good starting points.

Quoting the relevant parts here:

4. Use POST to Create a Resource

In order to create a new Resource in the API – we can make good use of the postForLocation(), postForObject() or postForEntity() APIs.

The first returns the URI of the newly created Resource while the second returns the Resource itself.

4.1. The postForObject API

```
ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = getClientHttpRequestFactory();
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

HttpEntity<Foo> request = new HttpEntity<>(new Foo("bar"));
Foo foo = restTemplate.postForObject(fooResourceUrl, request, Foo.class);
assertThat(foo, notNullValue());
assertThat(foo.getName(), is("bar"));
```

4.2. The postForLocation API

Similarly, let’s have a look at the operation that – instead of returning the full Resource, just returns the Location of that newly created Resource:

```
HttpEntity<Foo> request = new HttpEntity<>(new Foo("bar"));
URI location = restTemplate.postForLocation(fooResourceUrl, request);
assertThat(location, notNullValue());
```

4.3. The exchange API
Finally, let’s have a look at how to do a POST with the more generic exchange API:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpEntity<Foo> request = new HttpEntity<>(new Foo("bar"));
ResponseEntity<Foo> response = restTemplate.
exchange(fooResourceUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, Foo.class);
assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.CREATED));
Foo foo = response.getBody();
assertThat(foo, notNullValue());
assertThat(foo.getName(), is("bar"));
```

You'd do good with the post exchange API.

**Update**

Your json response is not valid. You need to change the rest api to return something like this

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "deviceId": 1,
        "userId": "100",
        "userName": "Jee",
        "date": "2016-09-19 00:00:00.000"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": 1,
        "userId": "100",
        "userName": "Jee",
        "date": "2016-09-19 00:00:00.000"
    }
 ]
}
```

When consuming this rest api, the response object will be

```
public class ResponseObject { 
private List<BiomatrixResult> results;

//getter setters
}
```

where your BiomatrixResult object will be

```
public class BiomatrixResult { 
private int deviceId; 
private String userId;
private String userName;
private Date date; 
//getters setters

}
```

Comment: {
   [
    {
      "deviceId": 1,
      "userId": "100",
      "userName": "Jee",
      "date": "2016-09-19 00:00:00.000"
    },  {
      "deviceId": 1,
      "userId": "100",
      "userName": "Jee",
      "date": "2016-09-19 00:00:00.000"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: i have that type json how to read in using restTempate in java

Comment: DATA LIKE  public class BiomatrixResult 
{
 @JsonProperty("deviceId")
 @XmlElement( required = true )
 private int deviceId;
 @JsonProperty("userId")
 @XmlElement( required = true )
 private String userId;
 @JsonProperty("userName")
 @XmlElement( required = true )
 private String userName;
 @JsonProperty("date")
 @XmlElement( required = true )
 private String date;

Comment: You can create a pojo class that represents your response data. You do need all those annotations. A simple pojo class will do. The attribute names will be mapped with the json key values.

Comment: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Unsupported Media Type,cause is :null.

Comment: 1. Please check my updated answer.
2. Please add whatever error or other details by editing the question, instead of adding them as comments.